# How to save gameobjects into prefabs or save lists(string) unity c# 3D

Tags: c#, save

I want to create a list that I can put strings in and save it close unity reopen it and load it.
Preferably, I would like to save the list itself, but anything else is appreciated. Thanks!

I tried google in youtube, but I didnt find any youtubers saving lists or gameobjects. I also tried the assetstore of Unity, didnt help.
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no code, and yes I know its a bot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your use case, [persistent data](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) or [player prefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) might be the keywords that you're looking for.

Comment: Player prefs save lists???

Comment: in string float only no?

Comment: But i will look into the persistent date, thanks!

Comment: @epidamir You could potentially flatten a list into a json string. Or the ease of use might've been worth storing each item separately in player prefs.